# How to send next.js client side data to the express server?

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js

For example, in my Next.js login component, I have an API call, which gives me some data

```
 submitLoginForm = e => {
   e.preventDefault();
   const loginData = {
     email: this.state.email,
     password: this.state.pass
   };

   axios.post("https://reqres.in/api/login", loginData)
  .then(res => console.log(res));

 };
```

I have an express server that handles server-side rendering. Now how do i send the response data from the client to the server.js file ??

Answer (score 4):

As you said, NextJS SSR is just an ExpressJS server that serves the app, you could add a route in the express file and have the client side send a request to that route.

server.js

```
app.get('/my/route', (req, res) => {
  // do something

  res.send('my route');
});
```

in your client side

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3000/my/route').then(console.log) // my route
```

**EDIT:**

Just to keep people from saying OP asked for POST method, not GET

Usage with POST

```
app.post('/my/route', (req, res) => {
  const { body } = req;

  // do something with body

  res.send('response after posting to server');
});
```

In your client

```
axios.post('http://localhost:3000/my/route', { data: [] })
  .then(console.log) // response after posting to server
```

Comment: He's asking how to send a POST request, not a GET request

Comment: @AljoshaNovakovic I don't see how that matters. This is just an example of how to use ExpressJS along side NextJS SSR... In any case, I have updated the answer with your great feedback :\

Comment: Haha yes it's basically the same, I just understood the question as more wondering how to send from the client side (whether GET or POST), and whether there was a built in nextjs way to do so (rather than w/ axios for example)